# Problemas com mascara em campo

Tags: android

Meu aplicativo esta fechando quando efetuo alguns clicks no campo, verifiquei que ele esta tentando adicionar duas vezes mascara ao campo.

```
@FocusChange(R.id.edtTelefone)
void focusAlterado(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    String telefone = edtTelefone.getText().toString();
    MaskEditTextChangedListener maskTEL = new MaskEditTextChangedListener("(##) #### ####", edtTelefone);
    if(!hasFocus) {
        if(telefone.length() != 14) {
            edtTelefone.addTextChangedListener(maskTEL);
            a++;
        }
    }else{
        if(telefone.length() == 0){
            edtTelefone.addTextChangedListener(maskTEL);
            a++;
        }else if(a != 1){
            edtTelefone.addTextChangedListener(maskTEL);
            a++;
        }
    }
}
```

Tentei fazer esta gambiarra de `a` porém não funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A máscara precisa ser adicionada apenas uma vez, sendo assim, você não deve tentar adicionar a cada vez que a view muda de foco. Você precisa adicionar a máscara através do onCreate(Bundle), no caso de uma Activity, ou do onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), no caso de um Fragment. Conforme mostra o exemplo abaixo:

```
MaskEditTextChangedListener maskTEL = new MaskEditTextChangedListener("(##) #### ####", edtTelefone);
edtTelefone.addTextChangedListener(maskTEL);
```